# Debounce function with args underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've got a function which takes in some arguments. But usage of underscore debounce is :

```
var lazyLayout = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
```

But in my case `calculateLayout` needs some arguments to run. How can I pass them in this case?

**Update :**

Sample `calculateLayout` function :

```
var calculateLayout = function(a,b) {
  console.log('a is ' + a + ' and b is ' + b);
}
```

Comment: not fully sure about this because I'm not fully hip to underscore yet, but if calculateLayout is a function, then pass the function with the args within an anonymous function. Or did you try this already?

Comment: Uh, [the `debounce` function](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-70) **does** pass on the arguments that were given? Just call `lazyLayout('a', 'b')`.

Comment: @Gandalf StormCrow, maybe you should unaccept my answer, as it's not really the most elegant solution but i can't delete it as long as it's accepted

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should be able to just use an anonymous function as the first argument, then call whatever you like in it:

```
_.debounce(function(){
    calculateLayout(20, 30);
}, 300);
```

Comment: this is exactly what i meant in my comment. perfect if it works.

Comment: Thanks! This also works for custom debounce method.

Answer (score 328):

You don't need an anonymous function in the middle, **arguments will automatically be passed to the original function when you run the debounced version**.

```
  var debounceCalculate = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
  debounceCalculate(a,b);
```

As an advantage you don't have to hardcode-bind the arguments in advance

You can try it and if curious just check the [source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L880)

Comment: This is good infor to know. Thanks for this. I have a hard time understanding why debounceCalculate is not declared as function here and is just assigned the debounce function and still acts like a function and is able to take the arguments and know that the arguments are for the inside function in the debounce. Why is that ?

Comment: If you check the source code of `_.debounce` you'll notice what it returns is a `function`. That's the power of functional programming and Js includes a bit of it :)

Answer (score 11):

@Jamie's answer is better.

I'll keep my original answer as below, although the it should be better to use Jamie's answer if you are familiar with JS:

```
var calculateLayout = function(a,b) {
  console.log('a is ' + a + ' and b is ' + b);
}

var debounceCalculate = _.debounce(function(a, b){
    calculateLayout(a, b);
}, 300);

debounceCalculate(1, 2);
```

Comment: uh...   `var debounceCalculate = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);` will suffice

Comment: @BradKent Thanks! I'll keep it as it is today since Jaime has already answered.

Comment: @jacobhobson Really don't know why you are doing this. First, I answered before Jaime's answer. Second, I think my answer is helpful to those JS beginners who don't quickly think of the args could be Omitted.

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody has written the one liner without extra `var` and `function`, I'll do it myself:

```
_.debounce(calculateLayout, 300)(a, b);
```

Debounce function returns another function, so you can call it just afterwards debounce is executed.

Comment: Defeats the purpose of debouncing completely

Comment: Isn't this wrong? I set exactly this to an event handler (eg. onClick) and it did not debounce at all. If you set this to an event handler it will **always create a new instance of the debounce function**