# How to use debounce with redux-form correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I have a search input.

```
const { searchMails } = this.props;
searchMails(keyword);
```

I added the lodash's `debounce` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910180/2000548) on Stack Overflow.

```
const { searchMails } = this.props;

const debounceSearchMails = debounce(searchMails, 1000);
debounceSearchMails(keyword);
```

The action

```
export const searchMails = keyword => ({ type: SEARCH_MAILS, payload: keyword });
```

However, after adding `debounce`, when I type "hello", it will still trigger 5 times `searchMails` after 1 second. The payload are

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```

How can I use debounce correctly? Thanks

**UPDATE 1**: add full codes

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, reset } from 'redux-form';
import { Form } from 'reactstrap';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

class Search extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    const { searchMails } = this.props;

    const debounceSearchMails = debounce(searchMails, 1000);
    debounceSearchMails(values.keyword);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, keyword } = this.props;

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        <Field name="keyword" component="input" type="search" onChange={() => setTimeout(handleSubmit(this.onSubmit))} />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};
  return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'searchForm'
})(Search);
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I changed my action to

```
const searchMails0 = keyword => ({ type: SEARCH_MAILS, payload: keyword });
export const searchMails = debounce(searchMails0, 1000);
```

But still same.

**UPDATE 3**: this time I changed to this, but still same.

```
class Search extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.debouncedSubmit = debounce(this.onSubmit, 1000);
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    const { searchMails } = this.props;
    searchMails(values.keyword);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, keyword } = this.props;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.debouncedSubmit)}>
        <Field name="keyword" component="input" type="search" onChange={() => setTimeout(handleSubmit(this.debouncedSubmit))} />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

**UDPATE 4:**

I found the issue is somehow related with `setTimeout`, if I have that like below, `debounce` won't work. If I remove `setTimeout`, `debounce` will work. But then `onChange` will always return last value. So I do need have it because of redux-form's [this "issue"](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/537)

```
<Field component="input" type="search" onChange={() => setTimeout(handleSubmit(debounce(this.onSubmit, 1000)))}/>
```

Comment: Show your component and an event handler.

Comment: @zerkms done! just add

Comment: You should only create the debounced function once and then use it. It is debounced function that holds internally the state necessary for debouncing. At the moment you recreate it on every keystroke.

Comment: @zerkms oh, thanks. check my new update. I changed my action, but still same. Maybe my usage is still wrong. Would you mind giving some suggestions?

Comment: You should not change the action creator implementation, you should change how you invoke it. Debouncing is the component's responsibility. Make your component having a debounced action. `this.debouncedSubmit = debounce(this.onSubmit, 300);` - something like that.

Comment: @zerkms just did, check my update. Still no luck..

Comment: You are still calling the action creator every keystroke: `handleSubmit(this.debouncedSubmit)`. You must invoke it from the `onSubmit` handler.

Comment: @zerkms I added another try. Sorry, I ran out of ideas..

Comment: You are not following what I recommended: `onChange={handleSubmit(debounce(this.onSubmit, 1000))}` --- you must create debounced function just **ONCE**. Then you should call it **DIRECTLY**.

Comment: As I mentioned few times - you are supposed to create the debounced function just once, then invoke it directly. So it should be `{this.debouncedSubmit}` and nothing more there.

Comment: @zerkms oh, I found my issue, it is because of the `setTimeout` in my onSubmit which causes the issue, once remove, the update 3 is actually also working. But there is a weird issue. I tried `onChange={handleSubmit(debounce(this.onSubmit, 1000))}`, when I type `hello`, it will only returns `hell`. I will try more, and reply back

Comment: It's not `setTimeout` causes the problem. At least not directly. Just do what I suggested above.

Comment: Hmm, it might somehow related with `setTimeout`. If I have that, it won't work.. If I remove, `debounce` will work. However, I need find another way to deal with "onChange does not have latest value issue [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/537)". I need find a way..

Comment: You don't need `setTimeout` in the `onChange` at all. `onChange` should be as simple as `this.debouncedSubmit`. If you don't understand what methods and when are invoked - take a debugger and inspect it.

Comment: @zerkms, if I remove `setTimeout`, onChange won't get latest value. I added in my UDPATE 4.

Comment: Update 4 is totally wrong. Please re-read the whole thread.

Comment: @zerkms I tried `onChange={() => handleSubmit(debounce(this.onSubmit, 1000))}`, which works perfect for debounce, but then without `setTimeout`, I cannot get latest value in onChange. I have to find a way making both debounce work and also get latest value in onChange.

Comment: Well, it's incorrect. I have explained why, but you continue doing it that way... Not sure why. If you simply followed my suggestions you could have had a working solution half an hour ago, but instead you write some random function calls, and are expecting it to work. The thing is - in programming calling random functions almost never lead you to the expected result. If you want to understand why your solution is wrong - take a debugger and step through your application.

Comment: @zerkms I got what you mean about `You should only create the debounced function once and then use it`, but I just cannot make both "debounce" and "getting latest value" work together. If you have a solution, would you mind posting a final working code in answer? I would like to try and accept it.

Comment: Create it once and invoke the debounced function directly (I mean **DIRECTLY**, like `onChange={this.debouncedSubmit}`, **WITHOUT** `handleSubmit`). And everything will work just fine.

Comment: Have you done **exactly** what I instructed 1 message above?

Comment: @zerkms, yes, I tried exactly, without `handleSubmit`, it will return nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157732/discussion-between-zerkms-and-hongbo-miao).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First big thank you for @zerkms. Without his guide to the right direction, I cannot make it.

> You should only create the debounced function once and then use it. It is debounced function that holds internally the state necessary for debouncing. At the moment you recreate it on every keystroke. – zerkms

After checking [onChange's type](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/f036f8773eb9fa5cd743b829bcfc752dfa64d25c/src/FieldProps.types.js.flow#L17), this is final working code:

```
class Search extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.debouncedOnChange = debounce(this.onChange, 1000);
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    const { searchMails } = this.props;
    searchMails(values.keyword);
  }

  onChange(event, newValue, previousValue) {
    const { searchMails } = this.props;
    searchMails(newValue);  // the second parameter is new value
  }

  render() {
    const { keyword } = this.props;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        <Field component="input" type="search" onChange={this.debouncedOnChange}/>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Lessons learned:

- I never thought I can do something like `this.debouncedSubmit = debounce(this.onSubmit, 1000);` in constructor.
- And I always thought I have to use `handleSubmit` from redux-form, but turns out it is not for all cases.
- Need go deep.

Comment: > "Need go deep."  

Comment: You could save those bind()ings by using an arrow function on onSubmit() and onChange()

Comment: Doesn't this debounce field typing experience?